# Alpine.js Focus and Keyup Event

Tags: javascript, focus, alpine.js

I have a webpage using [Alpine.js](https://alpinejs.dev) with [Focus Plugin](https://alpinejs.dev/plugins/focus) to open a modal when an item is clicked, I also want to be able to open the modal with the space bar and enter key

It works, but when using the enter key it seems to trigger again the click to the modal and it reopens at the moment

This is the code:

```
<div x-data="{ open: false }">  
<div class="mt-8 grid grid-cols-3 gap-8 mx-auto max-w-4xl">
    <div 
         class="aspect-square rounded bg-gray-300 grid place-items-center font-bold text-3xl"
         @click="open = 1" 
         @keyup.enter="open = 1" 
         @keyup.space="open = 1"
         tabindex="0"
         >1</div>
        <div 
         class="aspect-square rounded bg-gray-300 grid place-items-center font-bold text-3xl"
         @click="open = 2" 
         @keyup.enter="open = 2" 
         @keyup.space="open = 2"
         tabindex="0"
         >2</div>
        <div 
         class="aspect-square rounded bg-gray-300 grid place-items-center font-bold text-3xl"
         @click="open = 3" 
         @keyup.enter="open = 3" 
         @keyup.space="open = 3"
         tabindex="0"
         >3</div>
  </div>
  <div
            id="modal"
            class="bg-black/50 fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full p-4 grid place-items-center z-10"
            x-show="open"
            x-cloak
            x-trap.inert="open != 0" 
            x-transition.opacity
            >
            <div class="modal__body bg-white max-w-[760px] p-8 relative" x-transition.delay.50ms>
              <button 
                    type="button"
                    class="font-bold uppercase"
                    @click="open = false"
                    @keyup.enter="open = false" 
                    @keyup.space="open = false"
                    tabindex="0"
                    >
                    Close
                </button>
              <div>Modal content</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I've prepared a simple [CodePen](https://codepen.io/polsola/pen/poqgVbB) to see the issue, just tab to any element and hit enter to open modal, then hit enter to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<button>` elements automatically fire `click` events for <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> keypresses, on the `keydown` of the keypress.

Thus, when <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> is pressed down on the close button of the modal, the modal closes. However, focus is then returned the `<div>` and when one releases the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> key, this activates the `keyup` event listener.

To work around this, you could consider listening for `keydown` instead on the `<div>` elements:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@alpinejs/focus@3.13.0/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.13.0/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div x-data="{ open: false }">  
  <div class="mt-8 grid grid-cols-3 gap-8 mx-auto max-w-4xl">
    <div 
      class="aspect-square rounded bg-gray-300 grid place-items-center font-bold text-3xl"
      @click="open = 1" 
      @keydown.enter="open = 1" 
      @keydown.space="open = 1"
      tabindex="0"
    >1</div>
    <div 
      class="aspect-square rounded bg-gray-300 grid place-items-center font-bold text-3xl"
      @click="open = 2" 
      @keydown.enter="open = 2" 
      @keydown.space="open = 2"
      tabindex="0"
      >2</div>
    <div 
      class="aspect-square rounded bg-gray-300 grid place-items-center font-bold text-3xl"
      @click="open = 3" 
      @keydown.enter="open = 3" 
      @keydown.space="open = 3"
      tabindex="0"
    >3</div>
  </div>
  <div
    id="modal"
    class="bg-black/50 fixed top-0 left-0 w-full h-full p-4 grid place-items-center z-10"
    x-show="open"
    x-cloak
    x-trap.inert="open != 0" 
    x-transition.opacity
  >
    <div class="modal__body bg-white max-w-[760px] p-8 relative" x-transition.delay.50ms>
      <button 
        type="button"
        class="font-bold uppercase"
        @click="open = false"
        tabindex="0"
      >
        Close
      </button>
      <div>Modal content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```